# Progress bar for tdms file loading and optimisation of loading

Tags: python, optimization, progress-bar, loading

I'm loading big tdms files with TdmsFile() and I would like to add a progressbar that tells me the progress and how much time is left. I have tried progressbar and tqdm but I cannot find a way of implementing these to my code (below). Is this possible?

On a side note, the files are quite big and it takes more than 5 minutes to load each one. I have to do this multiple times, so I would like to find a way of optimising this without losing any data. Any ideas of how this could be done.

Thanks a lot.

This is the code I'm using:

```
tdms_file = TdmsFile(photometryfile) 
channel1_470 = tdms_file.object('Untitled', 'Voltage_0 (Filtered)')
channel1_405 = tdms_file.object('Untitled', 'Voltage_0 (Filtered) 1')
channel2_470 = tdms_file.object('Untitled', 'Voltage_1 (Filtered)')
channel2_405 = tdms_file.object('Untitled', 'Voltage_1 (Filtered) 1')
channel3_470 = tdms_file.object('Untitled', 'Voltage_2 (Filtered)')
channel3_405 = tdms_file.object('Untitled', 'Voltage_2 (Filtered) 1')
channel4_470 = tdms_file.object('Untitled', 'Voltage_3 (Filtered)')
channel4_405 = tdms_file.object('Untitled', 'Voltage_3 (Filtered) 1')
data1_470 = channel1_470.data
time1_470 = channel1_470.time_track()
data1_405 = channel1_405.data
time1_405 = channel1_405.time_track()
data2_470 = channel2_470.data
time2_470 = channel2_470.time_track()
data2_405 = channel2_405.data
time2_405 = channel2_405.time_track()
data3_470 = channel3_470.data
time3_470 = channel3_470.time_track()
data3_405 = channel3_405.data
time3_405 = channel3_405.time_track()
data4_470 = channel4_470.data
time4_470 = channel4_470.time_track()
data4_405 = channel4_405.data
time4_405 = channel4_405.time_track()
```